# Cannot run Xcode project when copy from pc

Tags: windows, macos

I want to copy the xcode project I saved in my pc to my Mac but I can't open it.

All the files in that project was added "._" in the their name.

How can I fix this? I don't have this project on my Mac anymore, only on pc.

Comment: Can you link to your project or sample files or etc ?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Sorry it's a private app so I can't show you but all the files's name is added "._" when I compressed it and open it in pc, example: ._ProjectName.xcworkspace

Comment: you can create a simple hello world app on your mac, move it to your pc and follow the issue scenario, then upload it and link here.

Answer (score -1):

Those `._`-files contain the extra file attributes that might not be available on other file systems. Typically you get them when you copy a file *from* your Mac to a file system that does not support extended attributes (like an USB flash drive with FAT). Therefore I expect that those `._` files alreday exist on your PC.

You should be able to simply delete them without any inconvenience; alternatively, you can use the tool `dot_clean` to merge them back.